# Failed to create function project when deploying firebase cloud function

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy the firebase function from my local machine

I run the following code:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I'm getting this error.

```
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (95.46 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 14 function messageNotification(us-central1)...
⚠  functions: failed to create function projects/xxx/locations/us-central1/functions/messageNotification
```

There isn't any error message. It merely stated that the function failed to be created. Does anyone know why? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I followed what John Hanley suggested and ran

```
firebase deploy --debug --only functions
```

and got the following error message

```
[2021-08-05T01:49:33.605Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 400 {"vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","date":"Thu, 05 Aug 2021 01:49:33 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T051=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2021-08-05T01:49:33.605Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE BODY {"error":{"code":400,"message":"The request has errors","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","details":[{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest","fieldViolations":[{"field":"event_trigger","description":"Expected value channels/{channelId}/{messageId} to match regular expression [^/]+/[^/]+(/[^/]+/[^/]+)*"}]}]}}
```

I realized the way I was writing the function was wrong. I was writing it

```
export const messageNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("channels/{channelId}/{messageId}")...
```

But I should have written it as shown below instead

```
export const messageNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("channels/{channelId}/messages/{messageId}")
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To debug deployments try two techniques:

Add the command line option **--debug**"

```
firebase deploy --debug --only functions
```

Check the logs for messages:

```
firebase functions:log
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure when you define the document trigger to use a correct selection of document in the form of

```
.document("Collection/{documentID}/nestedCollection/{nestedDocumentId}")
```

Answer (score 1):

For me updating firebase-tools make it works

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@latest
```